# Is a countable infinite union of $\Sigma_1$ sets is $\Sigma_1$?

Tags: set-theory, general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I’m reading Kunen’s book [Foundations of mathematics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Foundations_of_Mathematics/_B_oQQAACAAJ). My question is whether a countable union of $\Sigma_1$ sets in $HF$ is also $\Sigma_1$ or not. I wonder if we can think $\Sigma_1$ sets as open sets in HF.

Comment: What is HF? ${}$

Comment: @Wojowu Hereditarily finite.

Comment: What is an open set of HF? Is a countable union of countable sets of HF finite?

Comment: I suppose you mean whether a countable union of $\Sigma_1$ subsets **of** $HF$ is again a $\Sigma_1$ subset **of** $HF$?  A set that's actually *in* HF must be finite and so it can't be a nontrivial countable union of anything.

Comment: What have you tried?  For instance, you could edit Kunen's definition of $\Sigma_1$ into your question and explain where you got stuck in trying to prove that it's satisfied.

Comment: Singletons are $\Sigma_1$ subsets of HF; contemplate countable unions of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Sigma_1$ subsets of $\mathit{HF}$ are the recursively enumerable ones, as you might have read in Kunen's book. The intuition of being “open” sets is not completely incorrect, if you consider them *effectively open*.

With this in mind, it can be concluded that the union of an effectively  enumerated family of $\Sigma_1$ sets is again $\Sigma_1$. But, following Andreas' [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743945/is-a-countable-infinite-union-of-sigma-1-sets-is-sigma-1#comment7698998_3743945) above, any subset of $\omega$ can be obtained a countable union of $\Sigma_1$ sets; and there are indeed such sets that are not $\Sigma_1$— for instance, the set of (codes for) non halting Turing machines.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. When we think about "effective" topology by _effectively open sets_, how we can define compactness of a subset?

Comment: I wouldn't be sure what's the right answer here. Effective descriptive set theory provides corresponding definitions for concepts analogous to Borel and projective pointsets, and in particular lightface $\Pi_1^0$ correspond to complements of effective open set (thus they are _not_ r.e. sets). But in the field of [synthetic topology](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.entcs.2004.09.017), computability-aware versions of several concepts (in particular, compactness) are provided.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @minerva You're welcome!

Comment: @minerva I found another reference that addresses the compactness thing, [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.3763.pdf). Hope it helps. Also, if you are not expecting new new answer, you can [accept](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) mine.

Comment: Thank you for more information. This article seems very interesting and readable!