# Is there a "basis" or "subbasis" for semidecidability?

Tags: general-topology, decidability

There *seems* to be an analogy between semidecidability and topology, but to me, the "topology" seems to be weak. The usual definition of a topology over a space $X$ is:

- Statement #1: $\emptyset$ and $X$ are open.
- Statement #2: Union of arbitrarily many open sets is open.
- Statement #3: Intersection of finitely many open sets is open.

But the "topology" in analogy to semidecidability weakens Statement #2 to:

- Union of a computable sequence of open sets is open.

For example, give $\mathbb{N}$ the "topology" analogous to semidecidability. Then every singleton set is open (in fact, clopen). Let $H$ be the halting set. Then $H$ is open. But $\mathbb{N} \setminus H$ isn't open, despite being a countable union of singleton sets.

This means the usual basis (the singleton sets) doesn't "generate" the discrete topology.

I have so many questions, such as the impact on hierarchy of separation axioms, but for now, let me focus on one question. Is there a notion of "basis" for semidecidability? If so, how does it generate the "topology"?

Comment: How does your concept of "open set" relate to decidability? If a set is not a subset of $H$, why would it make sense to allow it be considered "open"?

Comment: @quasi Well, it isn't my original idea. Wikipedia says so. As for  a singleton set outside of $H$, we can just equality-compare Turing machines themselves.

Comment: Perhaps [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3744044/212120) to a recent question and its comments might be of use to you.